# ¿Porque el metodo __new__ se retorna a sí mismo?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Clase25():                                  
    def __new__(cls):                              
        print("This method executes first")    
        return super().__new__(cls)                
    def __init__(self):
        print("This method executes second")
objeto6 = Clase25()
```

*He visto multiples veces ejemplos donde el metodo new se retorna asimismo: "return super().__new __(cls)". No entiendo el objetivo de esto.*

Comment: Está llamando al __new__ de la super clase, no a si mismo.

Comment: Además, no se retorna a si mismo, sino que retorna lo mismo que retorna el `__new__()` de la superclase. Ya que la misión de `__new__()`  es crear un objeto nuevo, y esa no es tarea sencilla, en este caso simplemente delega en la clase superior esa creación. En python3 todas las clases que no declaran explícitamente de quién heredan lo hacen de la clase `object`. Por tanto se está llamando a `object.__new__(cls)` para que cree un nuevo objeto de la clase `cls`